# How do I implement a restart function after game over in my game?

Tags: c#, winforms, messagebox

I'm a beginner using Visual Studio to make a C# Windows Form. So I have a brick game (like the classic block game with ball and bricks) where if the player doesn't bounce the ball back, it's basically game over. However when this happens, the timer is just stopped and there's no way to restart. The code I have now just says to create a message box with "You lose" and you have to exit the program to play again. If you reach score 30 then that's a win and to play again you have to exit also.

I've tried googling this and the suggestions I see is if it's all set up already in their cases so implementing it to mine without having to re-do it all in someway is hard. I would like to make a simple implementation (or edit) where there is a play again function. How can I modify existing code to do this? Thank you dearly for any help.

This is the section of code that accounts for game-over if statement.
EDIT= Entire code provided.

```
        using System;
        using System.Collections.Generic;
        using System.ComponentModel;
        using System.Data;
        using System.Drawing;
        using System.Linq;
        using System.Text;
        using System.Threading.Tasks;
        using System.Windows.Forms;
        using System.Media;
        using System.Reflection;
        using System.IO;

       namespace FinalProjectGame
{

public partial class FrmGame : Form
{

    bool goLeft;
    bool goRight;
    int speed = 10;

    int pBallx = 5;
    int pBally = 5;

    int score = 0;

    public FrmGame()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

    }

    private void keyisdown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Left && btnGamer.Left > 0)
        {
            goLeft = true;
        }

        if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Right && btnGamer.Left + btnGamer.Width < 920)
        {
            goRight = true;
        }
    }

    private void keyisup(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Left)
        {
            goLeft = false;
        }

        if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Right)
        {
            goRight = false;
        }
    }

    private void TmrMainTimer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        pBall.Left += pBallx;
        pBall.Top += pBally;

        lblScore.Text = "Score: " + score; //keeping score 

        if (goLeft) { btnGamer.Left -= speed; } //izquierda 
        if (goRight) { btnGamer.Left += speed; } //derecha

        if (btnGamer.Left < 1)
        {
            goLeft = false; //disables "no-clip"
        }
        else if (btnGamer.Left + btnGamer.Width > 920)
        {
            goRight = false;
        }
        if (pBall.Left + pBall.Width > ClientSize.Width || pBall.Left < 0)
        {
            pBallx = -pBallx; //left, right wall bounce

        }

        if (pBall.Top < 0 || pBall.Bounds.IntersectsWith(btnGamer.Bounds))
        {
            pBally = -pBally; //top, bottom wall bounce

        }

        foreach (Control x in this.Controls)
            //main code brickies subtraction
        {
            if (x is PictureBox && x.Tag == "blockies")
            {
                if (pBall.Bounds.IntersectsWith(x.Bounds))
                {
                    this.Controls.Remove(x);
                    pBally = -pBally;
                    score++;

                } //end of main

                    //ALT method foreach (Control x in this.Controls)
                    //{
                        if (!(x is PictureBox))
                            continue;

                        //this is needed if some specific property of the PictureBox is needed.
                        PictureBox ctl = (PictureBox)x;

                        if (ctl.Tag.ToString() != "blockies")
                            continue;

                        if (!pBall.Bounds.IntersectsWith(ctl.Bounds))
                            continue;



                        //this.Controls.Remove(x);

                        x.Visible = false;

                        pBally = -pBally;
                        score++;
                    //}

            }

        }//----
        //This accounts for user score. Upon completing the game, the user wins. If the user does not capture the ball, it is automatically a game over.
        if (score == 30)
        {
            gameOver();
            MessageBox.Show("YES! WINNER!");
        }
        if (pBall.Top + pBall.Height > ClientSize.Height)
        {
            gameOver();
            MessageBox.Show("SORRY YOU LOSE!");


        }

        //======
    }
    private void gameOver()
    {
        TmrMainTimer.Stop();
    }

    private void FrmGame_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) //main form load
    {
        //load the splash screen form that was made with design view
        SplashScreen splash = new SplashScreen();
        splash.Show();

        //using system media to play the audio which is played upon start of the main form
        SoundPlayer Sndplayr = new SoundPlayer(Properties.Resources.RoleMusic);
        Sndplayr.Play();
    }

}
```

}

Comment: Essentially you will want to reset all your variables back to their initial state. How are you storing you data model?

Comment: Impossible for us to tell you how to implement this without known how your entire game is implemented. Do you have a game loop? Do you have game state objects? If your entire game "data" is stored within a game state object, then all you have to do is reset the state to default.

Comment: this really smells like homework to me!!

Comment: Create a "ResetGame" method that sets up the game (resets the score, ball position, etc). Create a "Start Game" button that the user can push to start the game (which will call the "ResetGame" method and start the timer, and presumably start the ball movement). Also add code to the click event that disables the button. In the "Game Over" method, re-enable the "Start Game" button so the user can play again.

Comment: Thanks to those who made suggestions.I have made the edit to my post that includes the entirety of my code. As for Moher I don't understand what the point of unnecessary comments/assumptions are for as it does not add anything useful. No it's not homework.

Comment: @Razgr1z often, providing the entire code is not helpful. In addition you haven't provided the more important code, the `SoundPlayer` class. But from what I can see, you call the `SoundPlayer.Play()` which presumably start the timer. And at the end of the game you stop the timer. So of course it wouldn't restart. So you need to give the user an option to ask if they want to restart, and if so, call `SoundPlayer.Paly()` again? And you'll probably need to reset variables in it to their initial states.

Comment: @Sach The sound media was when I wanted to learn how to implement audio when the main form (the game) loaded. I found a few suggestions from others who asked this and the main consensus was to add the using system media and then to put the audio line of code when the form loaded. This is under   private void FrmGame_Load(object sender, EventArgs e). On the other hand, the code that includes the messagebox is under the timer of     private void TmrMainTimer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)

Comment: Sorry I didn't understand what you meant. But anyway, assuming your Timer code works, we don't really need to see it. Please remove that, and add the parts where you start the timer (is it when a control event is triggered, or is it from within your `SoundPlayer.Paly()`? And still the basic idea of what I said stands; after game is finished, you need to command it to restart if the user so wishes. How to do it depends on how you start your game in the first place.

Comment: What is in your `SplashScreen` class? Nothing in the code you have posted sets up the blocks or the ball(at least not from what I saw).

Answer (score -1):

If you want to restart that WinForms application, use `Application.Restart()`. You may close your game form and call restart in your static `Main()` method afterwards.

```
private void TmrMainTimer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  ...

  if (pBall.Top + pBall.Height > ClientSize.Height)
  {
    gameOver();
    MessageBox.Show("SORRY YOU LOSE!");

    // close the game form
    this.Close();
  } 
}
```

And in your startup code:

```
  static class Program
  {
    /// <summary>
    /// The main entry point for the application.
    /// </summary>
    [STAThread]
    static void Main()
    {
      Application.EnableVisualStyles();
      Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
      Application.Run(new FrmGame());

      // restart application
      Application.Restart();
    }
  }
```

**Edit:**

The example above ist the easiest way to play that game from start. Of course, there are many other options:

1. As an extension, you can start your game form from a (maybe hidden) program startup form. If you register an event handler on the `FrmGame.FormClosed` event, you can restart that form again after the previous game was lost.
2. As many other guys suggested, a `StartAgain()` method, that resets your logic, is also an option.
3. Separate drawing logic (View) from game logic (Controller). For a such a simple game it is not necessary and overkill. But it is always a good idea to keep the things simple and clear. See the MVC pattern for your next project...